# How can I design a system that can use multiple versions (updates) of a key secret value stored in Azure Keyvault

Tags: azure, encryption, architecture, azure-keyvault, system-design

I have a file encryption/decryption logic that uses encryption-key stored in Azure KeyVault secret.
The key expires in 2 years and then we generate a new key and update the keyVault to use that for any encryption/decryptions from that time onwards. Now, when a new key is introduced, obviously the old encrypted files cannot be decrypted anymore with that.

So, I want to design the decryption process in a way that it keeps supporting decryption for all files (old or new) even after updating the key.

(The one option I thought of was get all versions of a keyValut secret and trying all version values until the one that decrypts the file - Not sure if its possible to access values in old versions of a keyVault secret)

Open to any idea/approach to reach the end goal of supporting old files' decryption in most efficient way.

Comment: Since you have all the versions of a keyvault secret, you can take the below approach. Use the version identifier of your secret, get hash of it, which would then be included in the encrypted resultant file name, say someFile_hashvalue.ext. When you are about to decrypt, get the hashvalue present in the filename and compare it with each of your secret's hash value, then you would come to know which version of your `secret` was used to encrypt that file. You can access values of the KV secret in old versions, unless they are disabled.

Comment: I like this approach, but in my case we have files that are already encrypted and in Prod. We won't be able to rename them and we updated the key once already. So there are files sitting there with some encrypted by old key and some with new.

Comment: In your case then, those older files need to be tried one version of your key at a time as you mentioned in the question, unfortunately I don't see any other way.